# Why isn't `ssh-keygen --help` going to stdout?

Tags: stdout, ssh-keygen

I wanted to search through the output of `ssh-keygen` by piping it through grep. To my surprise, that didn't work, so I tried directing the contents to a text file like so: `ssh-keygen --help > temp.txt` and that didn't work either. I've concluded that `ssh-keygen --help` does not print to stdout. So I have a specific question and general question please:

Specific: How do I get `ssh-keygen --help` to end up in stdout?

General: What is going on here? If not to stdout, then to what/where are the contents being 'directed', and how would I have gone about figuring that out?

Comment: This probably isn't it but isn't `ssh-keygen` interactive? Would that affect the results?

Comment: @Rietty: even with the --help flag? I guess they might have built it that way. Is there a way to find out?